# If check box checked disable other, if unchecked enable all in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, disable

I'm stuck in a sutiation where I need to disable the check boxs except the one which is checked.

The checkbox is dynamically created with the help of API and key will be passed to each checkbox. Is there a way to achieve above requirement.

Thanks

```
{this.state.imageinfo.map((image, key) => {
          return(
            <div key={key}>
              <input type="checkbox"
                onClick={(e)=> this.setCoverImage(e,key)}>Cover Image
              <div className="delete-image" onClick={() => this.removeImage(key)}>
                &times;
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
```

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 0):

You could have that checkbox change a boolean saved in state and have the disabled attribute of all the others equal to that sate object.

Answer (score 0):

use radio instead of checkbox

checkboxes behaviour is multiple selection, while radio isnt

if you want to use checkboxes:

```
setCoverImage(e, key) {
    ...
    this.setState({active: key})
}
render() {
    ...
    <input type="checkbox"
            onClick={(e)=> this.setCoverImage(e,key)} checked={this.state.active === key}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are required to set a checked keyword which is boolean in an array which is set in your state. When ever function is called then it will set checked keyword in only that element of Array where the key is provided. Rest of The checked keyword in Arrays will be deleted.and then you will set the Updated Array in your State. Like this.

```
setCoverImage=(key)=>{
const ItemKeyTobeChecked=key;
const imageinfoArray=this.state.imageinfo;

for(var i=0;i<imageinfoArray.length;i++){
 if(key===i){
  imageinforArray[key].checked=true;
 } 
 else{
   if(imageinforArray[i].checked){
    delete imageinforArray[i].checked
   }
 }
}
this.setState({
imageinfo:imageinfoArray
})
}
```