# facing issued with disabling checkbox in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working on disabling check boxes when i select  any one of them , the rest should be disabled.I have tried searching for it but didn't find anything relevant.Kindly help.

Comment: try to add snippets of code to get better answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally disabled React Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717752/conditionally-disabled-react-checkboxes)

Comment: Or this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853167/if-check-box-checked-disable-other-if-unchecked-enable-all-in-react

Comment: I've added a Runnable example for you to demonstrate my answer better. check it out

Comment: hi ,I need to enable that checkbox once it got disabled too,here I can't enable it once disabled.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create a state called `isDisabled` and change the state to true when one of checkboxes have been clicked, and use this state as `disabled` prop in checkbox

Something Like this:

```js
function App() {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(false);
  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = React.useState();

  const handleChange = e => {
    setCheckboxValue(e.target.value);
    setIsDisabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label>
          check 1:
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="check1"
            checked={checkboxValue === "check1"}
            onChange={handleChange}
            disabled={isDisabled}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          check 2:
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="check2"
            checked={checkboxValue === "check2"}
            onChange={handleChange}
            disabled={isDisabled}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          check 3:
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="check3"
            checked={checkboxValue === "check3"}
            onChange={handleChange}
            disabled={isDisabled}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```